# is there any way to stop python to concatanate space delimited strings?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Recently we found a couple of bugs in our code based because a developer forgot to add a comma in the middle of a list of strings and python just concatenated the strings. 
look below:

The intended list was:
["abc", "def"]

Developer wrote:
["abc"
 "def"]

and we got: ["abcdef"]

now I am concerned over similar mistakes in other part of the code, is this functionality a core part of python? is it possible to disable it?

Comment: `grep -IrH '"[^"]*"\s\+"[^"]*"' *` can help

Comment: This would be a good incentive to write tests for your code.

Comment: Why not use assertions to verify the length of the sequence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a [core part of python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly
>   using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is
>   the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent
>   to `"helloworld"`.

I don't think there is a way to disable it, short of hacking Python itself.

---

However, you could use the script below to [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) your code and warn you when it finds multiple adjacent strings:

```
import tokenize
import token
import io
import collections


class Token(collections.namedtuple('Token', 'num val start end line')):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return token.tok_name[self.num]

def check(codestr):
    lastname = None
    for tok in tokenize.generate_tokens(io.BytesIO(codestr).readline):
        tok = Token(*tok)
        if lastname == 'STRING' and lastname == tok.name:
            print('ADJACENT STRINGS: {}'.format(tok.line.rstrip()))
        else:
            lastname = tok.name


codestr = '''
'hello'\
'world'

for z in ('foo' 'bar', 'baz'):
    x = ["abc" "def"]
    y = [1, 2, 3]
'''

check(codestr)
```

yields

```
ADJACENT STRINGS: 'hello''world'
ADJACENT STRINGS: for z in ('foo' 'bar', 'baz'):
ADJACENT STRINGS:     x = ["abc" "def"]
```