# Linter that warns about implicit string concatenation in Python

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Is there an utility that parses a Python source file and warns about implicit string concatenation, like here:

```
a = ["foo"
     "bar"]
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026964/is-there-any-way-to-stop-python-to-concatanate-space-delimited-strings), but the provided program does not print file name and line number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a bounty question a few weeks ago asking the same. Maybe I can find it.

Comment: @timgeb: You are right.  I have found it.  Shame on me for relying on the automatic topic search instead of running my own search.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you give me the link? Then I can close this one here as a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546048/identifying-implicit-string-literal-concatenation